# Does the Primary Key in an Access Table ever change

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I'm currently working on an MS Access project (Office 2013, .accdb format). I have a table with a list of fields. Sometimes I want to export data from that table and name the export using the Primary Key. I generally understand how Primary Keys work and that it they shouldn't ever change.

What I'm wondering is if they ever do change (without the user explicitly changing them) e.g. when performing a Compact & Repair is it possible for the PK of an existing record to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a Primary Key will never change on its own.  You also shouldn't change one as a matter of course, as they are usually chosen for their ability to be unique, and most tables won't have more than a single field which contains completely unique values.

That's not to say that a Primary Key **can't** be changed manually, but it probably shouldn't be.  Its main purpose is to make joins with other tables, and searches within its own table, more efficient.  So, unless the most important and unique field changes, you should never change it.

Answer (score 1):

The database will not, on its own, change the value stored in a primary key column. A primary key is supposed to be three things: non-NULL, unique, and unchanging. Database software will enforce none, some, or all of these requirements for you, but no database I'm aware of will ever *change* the value of a primary key field without being explicitly instructed to do so (e.g. via a user-supplied UPDATE statement).

Best of luck.